# Final ん on a verb

Tags: dialects

I'm reading a book which I think use some dialect, not sure if Kansai or what else; there is a form I encountered a couple of times pages, and I'm not sure what it means:

> 亜也{あや}は勉強できるからいいじゃん。将来のことは好きな学科を生かせばいい。英語が得意だから徹底的にマスター**しりん**
>
> 歩道橋を渡るときも、カバンを持ってくれて、「手すりをつかんで**上がりん**よ」

Given those examples, I think it's the verb plus N: する > しり-ん; 上がる > 上がり-ん, but I'm not sure about it's meaning. I tried looking around on the Internet, but didn't find anything

Should it be read something like なさい, like 手すりをつかんで上がりなさい?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this usage.  That said, your analysis is a bit off -- the verb する would conjugate to just し, not しり.  The verb 知る【しる】 would conjugate to しり, but that doesn't seem to fit the context.  I wonder if the suffix here is りん instead of just ん?  But that wouldn't fit for 上がり【あがり】 + りん.  Maybe する → しり is another aspect of whatever dialect this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 三河弁｛みかわべん｝, a dialect used in parts of 愛知県｛あいちけん｝.

Conjugating with りん is a sort of "soft" imperative, suggestive rather than commanding.

As for your sentences, the parts with the りん therefore translate to the following:

```
You (亜也) are good at English, so you should master it completely.

(It is good to) hold the hand rail while going up.
```

Some other examples are

```
来｛く｝る　ー＞　来｛こ｝りん
食｛た｝べる　ー＞　食｛た｝べりん
```

Note that 五段活用{ごだんかつよう｝ verbs, such as 書｛か｝く　and 行｛い｝く do not get the り, but simply a ん like

```
書く　ー＞　書きん
```

I am not sure about Kansai, but on Kyushu a similar form is common with just the り part, such as 食{た}べり (する is conjugated to しぃ in this case on Kyushu). The ん is not added on Kyushu. On Kyushu ん is instead added in other conjugation to produce the negative of the verb.

Comment: FWIW, according to [the JA Wikipedia article on 三河弁【みかわべん】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E6%B2%B3%E5%BC%81#%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E5%90%84%E7%A8%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE), the negative there is also formed by adding ん, onto the 未然形【みぜんけい】 stem of the verb.  So しりん ("should do"), せん ("doesn't do").

Comment: しりん being an imperative, isn't the first sentence said directly to Aya? I didn't know this form in Mikawa-ben but I would understand it that way (as an equivalent of しぃ in Kansai). If this is indeed the case, your translation may be misleading.

Comment: @aguijonazo sorry, I'm not sure why I put "she", it should of course be Aya. I corrected this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi thanks for the link. Indeed, ん as a negative form is quite common throughout Japan. Interestingly I see in the link that some people say せん instead of しりん. From the sentence itself I guess there would not be any risk of confusion though.

Comment: I figure that the "should" version of ん might be a contraction of 〈連用形〉+ なさい → 〈連用形〉+ な → 〈連用形〉+ ん.  But I'm curious where that epenthetic り comes from for サ変 and 一段動詞?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not rather the opposite, that り came first since it is quite well-spread (maybe from some contraction with あり?), and that ん was added on top of this in 三河.

Comment: Both sentences are said directly to Aya, one from her mother, the other from her sister; in the first the mother is trying to cheer up Aya, since she's feeling down because she isn't good in athletic, and in the second the sister is carrying ther bag and saying her to hold the handrail since Aya has trouble moving.

Comment: This article says that this so called 連用形命令 comes from なさる, https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/nihongonokenkyu/9/3/9_KJ00008999970/_article/-char/ja/#:~:text=%E7%8F%BE%E4%BB%A3%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%2C%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE,%E3%82%92%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83%E3%81%AB%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82&text=%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E9%80%A3%E7%94%A8%E5%BD%A2%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4%E3%81%8C%E6%88%90%E7%AB%8B,%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82 e.g. お行きなされ　→　行き。maybe the り then comes from なさり?

Comment: @a20, interesting idea.  But if the り is from なさり, then where does the following ん come from?  Doubled なさり?  〈連用形〉+ なさり + なさり → 〈連用形〉+ り + な → 〈連用形〉+ り + ん?  But then why would this り only manifest for 一段動詞 and サ変動詞?